# Json data in fullcalendar

Tags: c#, javascript, fullcalendar

Using a javascript plugin Fullcalendar, and I'm trying to load data into the events handle in the javascript plugin. The data is being processed but isn't being displayed in the calendar.

If I was to guess the issue, I think it would have to do with my date format being returned, to the full calendar plugin. Is it supposed to be returned in unixtimestamp? Here is the Json result.

[image]

They're valid unixtimestamps. 
Here is my controller.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult CalendarData()
{
    DateTime start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    start = start.AddSeconds(double.Parse(Request["start"]));
    end = end.AddSeconds(double.Parse(Request["end"]));

    // call middle tier/orm/whatever to get data from source
    List<webby.Models.Calendar> list = SearchForEvents(start, end);

    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}


private List<webby.Models.Calendar> SearchForEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var eventList = (from e in db.Calendars
                     select new 
                     {
                         ID = e.ID,
                         title = e.title,
                         start = start,
                         end = end
                     }).AsEnumerable().Select(x=> new webby.Models.Calendar{ID=x.ID, title =x.title, start = x.start, end =x.end}).ToList();

    return (eventList);  
}
```

And my fullcalendar plugin:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            height: 170,
            selectable: true,
            editable: true,
            defaultView: 'basicWeek',
            events: "/Home/CalendarData",
            dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

                $.ajax(
                {

                    url: '@Url.Action("Index","Home")',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ date: date }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    cache: false

                }).success(function (response) {

                    $("#modalLoad").html(response);
                    $("#myModal").modal();

                }).error(function (a,b,c) {
                    alert(a.responseText);
                    alert(b);
                    alert(c);
                });



            }

        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that you can use UNIX timestamps here. I think it has to be something moment() can parse. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/